Offsetting the x tick labels to aim at the corresponding x tick

As you can see, the arrows are not exactly aimed at the corresponding x-tick, is it possible to offset the labels so that, for any reasonable rotation angle, say 50 ≤ θ ≤ 90, the arrows hit their x-tick?

Regarding How to move a tick label
I'm afraid it doesn't answer completely my question.

Using ha='right' is practically correct when θ≈45, otherwise the arrows miss their targets.
IOBE's answer tells me how to move by x points the labels, but doesn't answer HOW MUCH I must move them as a function of θ.


If you want to experiment, here it's my code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.subplot()
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set(bbox=dict(boxstyle='rarrow', pad=0), rotation=70)
plt.show()


Does this answer your question? How to move a tick label

@Vitalizzare I'm afraid it doesn't. ①Using ha='right' is practically correct when θ≈45, otherwise the arrows miss their targets. ② IOBE answer tells me how to move by x points the labels, but doesn't answer HOW MUCH I must move them as a function of θ.

Have you tried different values of verticalalignment with rotarion_mode="anchor"? Sort of  va = 'center' if rotation > 75 else 'baseline' if rotation > 35 else 'bottom' and then label.set(..., rotation=rotation, ha='right', va=va, rotation_mode='anchor')

@Vitalizzare Not yet… tonight maybe. Thank you for the suggestions.
